# BitLocker (Lost bitlocker password and recovery key)

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

Lost my bit-locker password and recovery key. I don't have any method unlock my partition. I tried to use some methods but i couldn't unlock my partition

Comment: This question should be left open as a warning to others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you've lost your password *and* your recovery key, then there is no way for you to access the data protected by BitLocker. If you could, under these conditions, then that means that anyone could and therefore the whole point of encrypting your drive is defeated.

Encryption isn't some programmatic "lock" that can just be "bypassed" or easily changed like local user credentials. It is a process by which the data you have stored - the actual virtual ones and zeroes themselves - get changed in such a way that it is impossible to restore them to their original state without the key. Additionally, encryption keys are designed such that it is mathematically infeasible for an attacker (and, at this point, "an attacker" means you or anyone acting on your behalf) to re-generate or derive the correct key on their own.

Having forgotten the password, and not being in immediate possession of the recovery key, your only chance at unlocking the drive is if you backed the key up to your Microsoft Account or cloud storage (e.g.: Dropbox, OneDrive). Backup of the key to your Microsoft Account can be done during setup for Windows 8 and later, but is not supported by any built-in mechanisms for Windows 7. Since you're using the latter, you would have had to first backup the key to an offline storage device (e.g.: USB drive) and then transfer it up to OneDrive or another cloud storage provider.

Comment: hi, Iszi... but have some true methods for unlock bitlocker encryption partitions. please, try to help me. or do you know, contact microsoft center(live) for get help t my question and resolve

Comment: @DewnSara_Hyo lszi is correct.  The point of BitLocker is to keep out anyone who does not have the necessary keys.  Unfortunately that includes you if you lost the keys.  No one will be able to help you (except perhaps the National Security Agency if you live in the US, but that's not going to happen).  BitLocker encryption is serious stuff and there are no "options" available for "recoverying" the data.  Either you have the keys/password, or you don't.  Sorry.

Comment: @DewnSara_Hyo You are just as capable of calling Microsoft for help as we are, and much better situated to ensure they address your specific concerns when you do. The *only* way Microsoft would be able to help you though, is if your BitLocker recovery key was backed up to your Microsoft Account via OneDrive. This option is only available for Windows 8/8.1 systems which are not joined to a domain, and you would have had to select it during BitLocker setup.

Comment: thanks....:) i'll try(win 7 system) but i'm not sure

Comment: @DewnSara_Hyo Windows 7 does not support backing up BitLocker keys to OneDrive during setup. You would have had to back up your key to a USB drive first, and then transfer it off from there to your OneDrive. It's generally safe to say that you would probably remember having done this.

Comment: @DewnSara_Hyo, As pointed out in the answer, if you don't have the key, you cannot access the data. The only thing you can do is format your pc and start from scratch. Any data you have backed up can be restored. Data that is on the encrypted drive is lost. As pointed out before, if it were possible to get past this encryption, it would've been a bad encryption, and no one would use it. It is unbeatable for a reason.

Comment: sorry, i couldn't resolve my problem and that's not a answer :(

Comment: @DewnSara_Hyo Unfortunately, this is the answer. Whether you like it or not is not going to change the fact that your data is irrecoverable until such time as you either remember the password or find the recovery key. Of course, someone could always find some flaw in the encryption algorithms or their implementation in BitLocker. However, that's been tried and tested - and some parts even thoroughly reviewed by the community - for years (BitLocker itself is over 7 years old), so don't hold out hope for it any time soon.